# Simple SIGTRAN STP using RestComm jSS7

Tags: restcomm

There was a thread that died out on the mobicents-public a couple of years ago about possibly creating a simple SIGTRAN only STP using the JSS7 stacks.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobicents-public/wDvelzJLtb8

Has anyone successfully created such an STP ?  I'm looking to build or reuse a basic software STP with GTT for lab work and testing (not production).  Any basic advice on approaching this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think anyone took it further and contributed it back in the open. Would this be something you would be interested in doing and lead the project ? We could potentially fold that into the https://github.com/RestComm/load-balancer project to start with

Comment: If I do go this route and make some progress I'll get back to you about folding back into the load balancer.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried Restcomm open source Sigtran stack instead  used Dialogic DSI Sigtran stack. DSI stack requires commercial license for host processes(SCCP, TCAP, MAP, INAP etc.) for running forever but host processes works with 1 hour limit without any license file to assist development or testing purposes as a courtesy by Dialogic.

If it is ok to restart application every hour, you can use its Global Title Translation configuration to define routing rules based on SCCP calling and called party address fields. It’s package comes with sample configuration for host processes and SS7 related configuration, there are also sample GTT rules.

Documentation can be found [here](https://www.dialogic.com/signaling-and-ss7-components/download/dsi-interface-protocol-stacks).